# Pagespeed insights showing 'Backend Error'

Tags: wordpress, web-optimization, pagespeed-insights

I am checking my website speed on Pagespeed insights but it always keeps me showing 'Backend Error'...

I have checked `max_execution_time` and input time and other things to troubleshoot the problem but still facing the issue..

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was due to an HTML tag `<img src="">`. When I replaced it with a div with background image then this error got solved. Hope this would help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all JS Errors and Remove break points, debuggers from JS and try again.